# how to write/read multiple object arrays using a text file [Java]

Tags: java

I want to write 3 object arrays to the same text file and load the data back to the arrays as well. However, I can only seem to get this to work with `arr1` with the below code. How can I change this code to write the data of all 3 arrays to the same file and load the data back to their respective arrays?

```
import java.io.*;

public class CarCenter implements Serializable {
    static CarCenter[] arr1 = new CarCenter[6];
    static CarCenter[] arr2 = new CarCenter[6];
    static CarCenter[] arr3 = new CarCenter[6];

    public static void write() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Data.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(arr1);
            oos.writeObject(arr2);
            oos.writeObject(arr3);
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void load() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Data.txt");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            CarCenter[] saved = (CarCenter[]) ois.readObject();
            arr1 = saved;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are only loading the value of arr1:

```java
public static void load() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Data.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        CarCenter[] saved = (CarCenter[]) ois.readObject();
        arr1 = saved;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

All you have to do is to read the other objects as well like this:

```java
public static void load() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Data.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        CarCenter[] saved = (CarCenter[]) ois.readObject();
        arr1 = saved;
        CarCenter[] saved2 = (CarCenter[]) ois.readObject();
        arr2 = saved2;
        CarCenter[] saved3 = (CarCenter[]) ois.readObject();
        arr3 = saved3;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

Want to learn more?

I suggest reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved the issue for me. Also thank you for the documentation! Grateful!

Comment: @PetemcVoy Please click on the check mark near my answer then. Have a nice day!